# How to use bootstrap modal with rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-modal

I would like to implement a boostrap modal in my rails application.
The button is displaying but when I click on it nothing appears :

```
/ Trigger the modal with a button
%button.btn.btn-info.btn-lg{"data-target" => "#myModal", "data-toggle" => "modal", :type => "button"} Open Modal
/ Modal
#myModal.modal.fade{:role => "dialog"}
  .modal-dialog
    / Modal content
    .modal-content
      .modal-header
        %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} ×
        %h4.modal-title Modal Header
      .modal-body
        %p Some text in the modal.
      .modal-footer
        %button.btn.btn-default{"data-dismiss" => "modal", :type => "button"} Close
```

I think I miss something. Those are my gems installed :

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'git://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.7'
gem 'foundation'
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
...
```

my application layout :

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title HealthyBox
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
    = csrf_meta_tags
```

application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: Have you added `@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";` this lines to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` ??

Comment: I forgot to include it in my post but yes I did

Comment: what about `//= require bootstrap-sprockets` in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you followed the below steps

Add below lines to `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"; 
@import "bootstrap";
```

**Note:** Make sure the file has `.scss` extension (or `.sass` for Sass syntax). If you have just generated a new Rails app, it may come with a `.css` file instead

And below  line to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

```
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

It will works fine.